# how can i refresh twitter filter stream thread in tweepy?

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter, tweepy

I use tweepy to track tweets with changing list of hashtags

```
twitterStream=Stream(OAuthObject,listenerFunction())
twitterStream.filter(track=[u'hashtags separated by comma'])
```

Now every 3 hours ,i should get the latest hashtags from database , and refresh the stream thread , how can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it when i take a look to a Stream class constructor and found (async) parameter,and set it to true ,and here is my code :

```
twitterStream=Stream(OAuthObject,listenerFunction())
while True:
    if twitterStream.running is True:
        twitterStream.disconnect()
    keywords=getKeywordsFromDb() # return string of keywords seaprated by comma
    if keywords=='':
        print 'no keywords to listen to'
    else:
        twitterStream.filter(track=[keywords],async=True) # Open the stream to work on asynchronously on a different thread
    time.sleep(3600) # sleep for one hour
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that as of v3.8.0, the `async` parameter has been renamed `is_async`.

Comment: Now it is `threaded`

Answer (score 0):

You can return `False` from `on_status`, or some other callback method. This cancels the stream, which returns control back to your application.

In the `on_status` method, you could check the current time, and return `False` if three hours have passed. You could then call `filter` again, passing different hashtags from your database query.